# Is there any function increase line in openGl

Tags: opengl, line, opengl-compat

I want to create a line at (0,0)(1,0), then create (0,0)(2,0), then 3, 4,... up to 10, then again back (9,0)....(1,0). Is there any way how to do this?

```
void DrawLine(int a) {

    glBegin(GL_LINES);{
        glVertex3f(a,0,0);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);

        glVertex3f(0,a,0);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);

        glVertex3f(-a,0,0);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);

        glVertex3f(0,-a,0);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);

    }glEnd();
}
```

Comment: This question is almost unclear. What's wrong with `DrawLine(1)`, `DrawLine(2)`, `DrawLine(3)` ...?

Comment: Its called `for` loop ...

Comment: Can you post a sketch of what you want your line to look like in the end?